# Flip x-axis of matplotlib graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to flip the x-axis, it is listing dates and for some reason it has the most recent date close to the origin and earliest further to the right. I'm not sure why this happened. I tried including `set(gca,'xdir','reverse','ydir','reverse')` in the function below, but it didn't work, I got an error saying gca isn't found. Below is the code I have for the plot.

```
def plot_similarities(similarities_list, dates, title, labels):
    assert len(similarities_list) == len(labels)

    plt.figure(1, figsize=(10, 7))
    for similarities, label in zip(similarities_list, labels):
        plt.title(title)
        plt.plot(dates, similarities, label=label)
        plt.legend()
        plt.xticks(rotation=90)
    plt.show()

file_dates = {
    ticker: [ten_k['file_date'] for ten_k in ten_ks]
    for ticker, ten_ks in only_10ks_by_ticker.items()}  

plot_similarities(
    [cosine_similarities['AMD'][sentiment] for sentiment in sentiments],
    file_dates['AMD'][1:],
    'Cosine Similarities for {} Sentiment'.format('AMD'),
    sentiments)
```

What I would like is for the time values to be on the x-axis in ascending order, so earliest to the left and most recent to the right.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can grab the current axis and then invert:

```
ax=plt.gca()
ax.invert_xaxis()
ax.invert_yaxis()
```

Or you can store the axis object when plotting

```
ax=plt.plot(.....)
ax.invert_xaxis()
ax.invert_yaxis()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Would I include those lines in the function `plot_similarities`? It didn't do anything so I think I'm not sure where to put those lines lol

Comment: yup, they should go in the function. If it's not working you'll have to provide a complete working example: `only_10ks_by_ticker` is not defined in your code snippet and so I couldn't run it and gave you a general answer.

Comment: Ah okay, yeah it is a dictionary that I created, the code is rather long though. Before I resort to that, I forgot to ask, the 3 lines of code you suggest, would they go in a specific spot in the function I defined? I put them inside the for loop (at the end of it), maybe that was the issue. Could you explain where exactly you'd suggest inserting those 3 lines (`ax=plt.gca()
ax.invert_xaxis()
ax.invert_yaxis()`) Thanks!

Comment: Just provide a made up `only_10ks_by_ticker` so that you have a minimal example (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ) But the `ax.invert_xaxis()` normally would go immediately after you make a plot. Since it's in a loop it may be overwriting axes in a weird way? So you can also instantiate an axis before the loop with `ax=plt.axes()` and then every time  you plot, use `ax.plot()` instead of `plt.plot()`  and then outside the loop `ax.invert_xaxis()` should work. If it doesn't, something else is going on and you need to provide a complete working example.

Comment: Thanks :) I will give it a try and can provide a working example if it doesn't work. Cheers!